# how to detect event tap on specific image

Tags: android, nativescript, gesture, nativescript-telerik-ui

`var gestures = require("ui/gestures");`

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      imgArray[i] = new imageModule.Image();
  imgArray[i].id = "img";
  imgArray[i].width = w / 6;
  imgArray[i].height = h / 7;
  imgArray[i].src = images[i];
  imgArray[i].stretch = "fill";
  wrap_layout.addChild(imgArray[i]);
  imgArray[i].on(gestures.GestureTypes.tap, function (args) {
    console.log("tap"+"|"+i);
  });
```

this my loop adding array of images to WrapLayout on nativescript is work well my problem is I'm trying to implement tap gesture for each image is work but doesn't specific index of Image  any idea how solve it

Comment: So I guess your problem is that the logged index is always the number of images?

Comment: yeah exactly after some time of debugging i find solution for it

Comment: Then provide the solution here and mark your own answer as accepted, please ;)

Comment: sure ;) i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var onTap = function (args) {
console.log('tap');
 };
 images = raw_data.split("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          var m = re.exec(images[i]);
          idArray[i] = m[0];
          images[i] = images[i].replace(idArray[i], "");
          imgArray[i] = new imageModule.Image();
          imgArray[i].src = images[i];
          imgArray[i].stretch = "fill";
          stackArray[i] = new StackLayout();
          imgArray[i].id = "img";
          imgArray[i].width = sw;
          imgArray[i].height = sh;
          stackArray[i].id = "stack";
          stackArray[i].width = sw;
          stackArray[i].height = sh;
          stackArray[i].num = i;
          stackArray[i].addChild(imgArray[i]);
          wrap_layout.addChild(stackArray[i]);
          stackArray[i].on(buttonModule.Button.tapEvent, onTap, this);
        }
```

**that's work for me**